# Using "and" multiple times within a list

Tags: commas, lists, oxford-comma

The sentence in question is:

> Today I went to the store, bought eggs, cheese, and milk, and bread.

Is it ever proper to write the first and? Other cases I find use the and to connect one thing together (Tom and Sue Banks, for example). I haven't seen anything on this usage of "and" in particular.

Comment: How has nobody responded to this ?